# Increase storage size of a VM inside VMWare Workstation

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, storage

I have a windows 10 running on VM. I started with 50 GB. It too small for me now. I want to increase to 150 GB. I power off and expand in the VM settings to 150 GB already as you can see.

[image]

I restart the VM again, and still see the old storage size (50 GB).

[image]

Can someone please help ?

---

I would like to add, I can see that 100 GB now, I open up Disk Management and trying to select my C Drive and expand it, but all I see the shrink option, and my expand button seems grey out.

Do I need to format it before ?

[image]

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004047   ...... Make sure any snapshots have been resolved (you cannot expand with snapshots in place). Make sure the machine was OFF before trying to expand. Then if all fails, try to find a copy of VCenter Converter and use that to expand the file.

Comment: You need to also increase the size of the partition from within Windows using Disk Management.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't see the expand button enabled. Did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: @John Thanks for the link, reviewing now.

Comment: @John I followed link told already as steps 1 increased to 150GB, but I don't know how to make my VM to take that extra space that I allocate.

Comment: @code-8 - You have 100 GB of unallocated space on the virtual drive.  What exactly is your question?  You need to assign a drive letter to that unallocated space, or move the recovery partition, and extend the system volume like you want.  How you do either of those is well documented.  What step of that process are you stuck on?

Comment: I just expanded an Ubuntu VM from 50 GB to 100 GB - single file and it worked fine. The machine restarted and is running.

Comment: @Ramhound my question is my VM storage is still 50GB as suppose to 150 GB as I wanted it to. I see 2 partitions. I think I need to merge them somehow, but I can't or don't know how.

Comment: Now, I have 2 partitions 50GB and 100 GB. I don't see instruction on how to merge them into one as 150 GB. If you can confirm that the instruction on how to do that in the link , please let me know. I don't see them. Sorry...if I missed it.

Comment: @code-8 - You expanded the virtual HDD on the host system, which allows you to extend the drive within the guest os, you have not created a partition to use that additional 100 GB of unallocated space.  The reason you are unable to extend the system partition is that the recovery partition, is between the unallocated space and your system partition, moving or deleting (then recreating the disk at the end o the partition list) the recovery partition is the solution to that problem. The duplicate I proposed is only ONE solution to your problem which is fairly typical.

Answer (score 1):

There is a partition in the way that prevents you from expanding your main partition.

The best thing you can do is use a partition manager (not disk manager) such as AIOMEI Partition Assistant that can perform partition move operations outside of windows by booting into its own environment.

From there, you want to move the 500 mb partition all the way to the end. After that, you can extend the partition, but next time you make the partition bigger, you run into the same problem. Its therefor better to also move the main partition to the right, then move the 500mb partition to before the main partition.

With AIOMEI Partition Assistant, I find it works best if you perform each operation seperately. Queueing multiple operations seem to fail most of the time which means no operation took place.