# Extending the C drive in windows 11

Tags: partitioning

I need to extend my c drive but I was unable extend it because it got blocked by the healthy drive partition. What can I do to extend the volume of c drive?

This is how my disk looks like:
[image: image of my disk]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase storage size of a VM inside VMWare Workstation](https://superuser.com/questions/1720873/increase-storage-size-of-a-vm-inside-vmware-workstation) / see the answer about AIOMEI Partition Assistant (free)

Comment: Basically: Allocate + format that remaining 411GB; move files from D, E and/or F there; remove D, E and/or F partitions; remove the 600 MB partition; extend C. There may be tools that do it for you though.

Comment: It is SO much vastly easier just to let Windows 11 assign the partitions.

Comment: Thanks mate I will let you know after I done it.

Answer (score 0):

**What:**

Create adjacent free space to extend into.

**Why:**

You can only extend partitions into directly adjacent space. If you wanted to extend the C: partition by 100GB, you need an adjacent 100GB block (unallocated or empty).

Windows prevents system partitions being moved around while the system is on, *including the 600MB one that's in the way*, so you may need to use additional software.

**How:**

There's a few different ones but for this example I'll use GParted (GPartedLive mounted to a USB) since it's the one I'm most familiar with.

Booting into GParted, you could move each partition to the right by 100GB, starting with the rightmost partition and continuing backwards (F:, then E:, then D:, then the 600MB). This will leave 100GB unallocated space adjacent to the C: partition which can then be extended into. After extending it, that 600MB system partion will be directly adjacent to the C: drive.

*optional: (before you do any of this) run chkdsk then defrag each partition to reduce potential file corruption headaches.*

Comment: What using gparted to move the partitions should be safe, it is advisable to backup all partitions to an external hard drive in case something goes wrong along the way. I would use `dd` within Ubuntu Live to accomplish such backups.